# Enable Parcellite indicator in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: indicator

Is it still possible to enable the Parcellite indicator in Ubuntu 12.04? I've noticed that the indicator no longer shows up when I launch Parcellite. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the latest releases [**Parcellite**](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/) claims to support Unity. Debian packages without an application indicator are available from the project's home page. There we also have an [announcement for a ppa](https://launchpad.net/~rickyrockrat/+archive/ppa) that is supposed to contain the application indiciator once it is populated.

Alterantively you may install its fork [**ClipIt**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clipit) [image: Install clipit] instead.

[image: Install via the software center]

In case you do for any reason need to further run **Parcellite** you may whitelist its panel icon by running dconf-editor (from [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools]) *Desktop -> Unity -> panel* or from the command line

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['parcellite']"
```

Comment: Is it possible that Unity will eventually become backwards-compatible with applications that are now compatible with GNOME 2, but not Unity (such as Parcellite)?

Comment: You can also whitelist ['all'] for all legacy status icons. ClipIt is based on Parcellite.

Comment: Also, the Cinnamon desktop appears to be compatible with applications that do not yet work with Ubuntu's Unity desktop environment.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Parcellite is maintained, and I just released an appindicator .deb for it. Check out the web page for Parcellite. I only have an AMD64 machine with libappindicator, so that's the only deb for Unity I built.

http://parcellite.sourceforge.net

Comment: Can you setup a PPA for it? Then you'll have 32 and 64 bit versions.

Comment: The deb files are there for download. But you're right, a ppa would solve my build problems.

Comment: Done, https://launchpad.net/~rickyrockrat/+archive/ppa

Comment: Life is never easy. Finally got the ppa working:  https://launchpad.net/~rickyrockrat/+archive/parcellite-appindicator The non-appindicator ppa builds are here: https://launchpad.net/~rickyrockrat/+archive/parcellite